# strange error: resource not found on url mapping spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Everything seems alright but when I launch my application, I get a strange error of resource not found.
This is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private IMusicStoreService musicStoreService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

        return new ModelAndView("home","musicDetForm",new MusicDetails());
    }

        @RequestMapping(value="AddSong",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public String addSong(@ModelAttribute("musicDetForm") MusicDetails musicDetails){
           return musicStoreService.addSong(musicDetails);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "SongList/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public List<MusicDetails> getSongList(){
            return musicStoreService.getSongList();
        }
}
```

This is a code section from my pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>
```

This is my web.xml file

```
<display-name>MusicStore</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>aish.vaishno.musicstore</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

When I launch my application on tomcat using sts, no error is shown on my build but I get this error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MusicStore/
```

Why am I getting the above error despite that my mapping seems okay.

Comment: what is the URL you are trying?

Comment: where is your `/MusicStore/` mapping in `Controllor. we didn't find this mapping actually.

Comment: @Rahul http://localhost:8080/MusicStore/

Comment: @VikrantKashyap @RequestMapping(value="/")

Comment: if you are trying to access `/MusicStore/`, shouldn't you annotate you controller class  with `@RequestMapping('/MusicStore')`?

Comment: I will suggest first check your context name of the application. I mean to say first disable your spring config and check weather you are able to get index.html by this URL. Otherwise you are using wrong context name (URL) for your application.

Comment: Your controller is messed up. You are trying to access /MusicStore mapping, where is it in the main post? Why are you using block letters in your mappings, mappings are case-sensitive, you should use lower-case. What is your context-path?

Comment: /MusicStore is the entry point of my application. Even if I do this /MusicStore/AddSong it is still not thesame error thing

Comment: @WeareBorg this is my context path /MusicStore

Comment: Then your URL should be `/MusicStore/`. Also, what Patrick just  said now is also important, the code is messed up. YOu have not changed your mappings yet. Post a screenshot in the main post of your context path.

Comment: @WeareBorg Please check this resource, this is the url for the tutorial I am following up online https://aishwaryavaishno.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/spring-mvchibernate-annotation-based-mysql-maven-json-simple-example/

Comment: https://github.com/AishwaryaThangavelu/Spring-Repository/blob/master/MusicStore/src/main/java/aish/vaishno/musicstore/controller/HomeController.java

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the MusicStore inside the WEB-INF/?
It is okay to access if you set it as the index in web.xml

However,once you send request ,the response normally send to the URL you provided, and should be a 'JSP' file,but not servlet.

In your case, the code are messed up quite a bit,i didn't see any View or JSP or web page to follow your MusicStore controller, sure you can directly print it but that's not a good practice.

If you could provide more of the code content,it may be more helpful.
The solution is now see if you could access index page when you first load your servlet, or check the mapping.

Comment: This is the resource for the tutorial I am following up on https://aishwaryavaishno.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/spring-mvchibernate-annotation-based-mysql-maven-json-simple-example/

Comment: please check your code with the source code side by side to see what happened 
link: https://github.com/AishwaryaThangavelu/Spring-Repository/tree/master/MusicStore

Comment: Look at this section in my code @RequestMapping(value="/")
 public ModelAndView test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
            
  return new ModelAndView("home","musicDetForm",new MusicDetails());
 }

Comment: It returns the ModelAndView to the home.jsp

Comment: so now you are missing the home.jsp file so it says resource not found? My mind is a mess now , i don't even know how to help you, can you specify the problem you are facing now>?

Comment: If you check the controller, you will see that it is thesame with my controller https://github.com/AishwaryaThangavelu/Spring-Repository/blob/master/MusicStore/src/main/java/aish/vaishno/musicstore/controller/HomeController.java

Comment: i guess you can add a home.jsp and being mapped to the servlet or url response

Comment: The home.jsp is defined in the webapps folder. I am not missing the home.jsp file

Comment: Good then, so now you got home,jsp , and indeed you put it into webapps not inside the WEB-INF? that's still alright, the problem now i noticed is that, you didn't give the correct path to the 'home.jsp' so the error says resource not found, you now simply put your home.jsp to a reachable path,such as WEB-INF/ and dispatch it with "WEB-INF/home.jsp"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110356/discussion-between-jng-and-patrick-so).