# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered SpringMvc

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I am following up the solution I found here
 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8924825/5246735
and so this is my web.xml file

```
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    </web-app>
```

But when I launch my application I get this

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found.

Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `applicationContext.xml` in `WEB-INF` with this content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    </beans>
```

Add following code in `web.xml` file, because it looks for context to load so we have to declare it first.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### Resource Link:

[Spring - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569826/spring-no-webapplicationcontext-found-no-contextloaderlistener-registered)

Comment: A file named `applicationContext.xml` is automatically loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` so no need to add a `contextConfigLocation` also it is confusing because you suggest to create an `applicationContext.xml` but tell him to load a different one. Also the suggestion is even dangerous as according to the name of the file it should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` (this configuration would/could lead to duplicating all the beans and basically loading your application twice!).

Comment: @SkyWalker Please can you help me on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884731/strange-error-resource-not-found-on-url-mapping-spring-mvc Thanks

Comment: @JnG Ok. I will let you inform. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in web.xml file, bcs it looks for contex to load so we have to declare it initially.

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```